# Firestore rules to Read, Update and Delete

Tags: google-cloud-functions, firebase-security

I’m a non developer that is looking for some guidance with security rules for a Firestore project.

Firestore database screenshot:

[image]

Each document in the **Swaps** collection should be accessible by two users only, a giver and a receiver.

To be allowed to create a new document in the **Swaps** collection, the user needs to assign herself as the receiver, which means the authenticated userid must match the **ReceiverID** of the request.

However, both the giver and receiver should be allowed to Update, Read and Delete the document. To do this, I want to match the receiver to the Swap document's **ReceiverID** and the giver to the Swap document's **GiverID**

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
 match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Swaps/{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.GiverID;
      allow update: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.GiverID;
      allow delete: if request.auth.uid ==resource.data.GiverID;
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.ReceiverID;
      allow update: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.ReceiverID;
      allow delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.ReceiverID;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.ReceiverID; 
    }
```

Currently, the only rule that seams to be working is Create. Read, update and delete are not working, either for giver or receiver.

Comment: First thing you should do is to remove the `read` rules. You have them twice, and since you want to use granular rules neither of them is needed (and might actually be causing problems). If after that you still have the problem, edit your question to update the rules, and include the code of the operation that doesn't work (since rules only gain meaning from the code that you run against them).

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
 match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Swaps/{Swap} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.GiverID || request.auth.uid == resource.data.ReceiverID;
      allow update: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.GiverID || request.auth.uid == resource.data.ReceiverID;
      allow delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.GiverID || request.auth.uid == resource.data.ReceiverID;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.ReceiverID; 
    }
```